# Obtener el Registro Anterior en Consulta Mysql

Tags: mysql

tengo la siguiente consulta Mysql:

```
SELECT

      row_number() OVER (ORDER BY cc.fecha) AS contador,
      dc.id,
      dc.id_comp,
      dc.concepto,
      tc.nombre AS tipo_comprobante,
      cc.fecha,
      cc.id AS id_cc,
      dc.debe,
      dc.haber

      FROM detalle_comprobantes dc

      INNER JOIN comprobantes_contables cc ON cc.folio_comp = dc.id_comp
      INNER JOIN tipo_comprobantes tc ON tc.id = cc.tipo_comp

      WHERE dc.empresa = 2 AND cc.empresa = 2 AND dc.cuenta = 2104003 AND cc.fecha BETWEEN '2021-09-01' AND '2021-10-30' ORDER BY cc.fecha, tc.id, cc.folio_comp ASC
```

Lo cual me devuelve esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es tomar el debe y haber anterior, en caso que sea el primer registro, deberia mostrar cero.
Todos los ejemplos que he visto, trabajan con el ID de la consulta, pero en teoría no me serviría, ya que los resultados y los ID varían y no son correlativos porque dependen del WHERE en la consulta.
Lo que pretendo lograr es generar una nueva columna llamada Saldo que se genera de la siguiente manera:

- Si el valor el Null, seria debe - haber (primer registro de la consulta).
- Desde el segundo registro, debería tomar el saldo anterior(generado en la primera consulta), sumar el debe y restarle el haber, lo cual genera un nuevo saldo.
- Para los demás registros, los saldos son generados tomando los valores del registro anterior.
  Gracias por cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En MySql 8.0 o superior lo puedes hacer utlizando la función de ventana `SUM()`, que va calculando la suma acumulada:

```
SELECT
      row_number() OVER (ORDER BY cc.fecha) AS contador,
      dc.id,
      dc.id_comp,
      dc.concepto,
      tc.nombre AS tipo_comprobante,
      cc.fecha,
      cc.id AS id_cc,
      dc.debe,
      dc.haber,
      SUM(dc.debe - dc.haber) OVER (ORDER BY cc.fecha) AS saldo
      
FROM detalle_comprobantes dc

INNER JOIN comprobantes_contables cc ON cc.folio_comp = dc.id_comp
INNER JOIN tipo_comprobantes tc ON tc.id = cc.tipo_comp
WHERE dc.empresa = 2 AND cc.empresa = 2 AND dc.cuenta = 2104003 
      AND cc.fecha BETWEEN '2021-09-01' AND '2021-10-30' 
ORDER BY cc.fecha, tc.id, cc.folio_comp ASC;
```

En MySql 5.7 lo puedes hacer utilizando una variable que almacene el `saldo`:

```
SET @saldo:=0;

SELECT
      row_number() OVER (ORDER BY cc.fecha) AS contador,
      dc.id,
      dc.id_comp,
      dc.concepto,
      tc.nombre AS tipo_comprobante,
      cc.fecha,
      cc.id AS id_cc,
      dc.debe,
      dc.haber,
      @saldo:=@saldo + (dc.debe - dc.haber) AS saldo
      
FROM detalle_comprobantes dc

INNER JOIN comprobantes_contables cc ON cc.folio_comp = dc.id_comp
INNER JOIN tipo_comprobantes tc ON tc.id = cc.tipo_comp
WHERE dc.empresa = 2 AND cc.empresa = 2 AND dc.cuenta = 2104003 
      AND cc.fecha BETWEEN '2021-09-01' AND '2021-10-30' 
ORDER BY cc.fecha, tc.id, cc.folio_comp ASC;
```

Comment: Estimado, gracias por responder. Probé tu código pero solo me entrega el total acumulado de todos los debes y haberes. Es algo que ya había intentado antes. Saludos y gracias

Comment: De nada @maha1982! **NO** estoy usando la función de agregación `SUM()` (no uso la claúsula `GROUP BY`), sino la función de ventana `SUM()`: para cada fila retorna la diferencia entre el debe y el haber de la fila, mas el valor del saldo de la fila anterior ordenando por `cc.fecha` (según entendí eso es lo que solicitabas, sino es así aclarame cual es tu requerimiento). Si compartes los `CREATE TABLE` y los `INSERT` con datos de prueba lo podríá probar.

Comment: Muchas gracias, comparto los datos de prueba editando mi publicación o por algún otro método? Saludos y gracias nuevamente.

Comment: De nada! Edita tu pregunta y agregua allí los valores de prueba. En este pequeño [ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ea8e3561018f145595a4b57815f00f8c) podrás ver que los valores de `saldo` son los que vos esperas.

Comment: pequeño gran detalle, estoy usando Mysql 5.7. Lo siento, se me olvido mencionarlo.

Comment: El problema que veo, es que todos los registros tiene la misma fecha, por lo tanto deberás agregar algún otra columna para ordenar, según el orden en que se fueron insertando los asientos.

Comment: Agregué una solución para MySql 5.7 utilizando una variable que almacena el saldo.

Comment: Con este ultimo ejemplo y haciendo mención a lo que dijiste sobre el orden, efectivamente la forma o las condiciones de orden de los datos, altera el resultado. Buscaré la forma correcta de ordenar los datos y te comentare como me va. Agradecido por tu ayuda. saludos

Comment: De nada @maha1982! Me alegra haberte ayudado, saludos!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130612/discussion-between-maha1982-and-nachospiu).

Answer (score 0):

**Saludos.**

Te sugiero usar [WITH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) de MySQL; aquí el "truco" será que puedas generar un ID (no sé si fue lo que quisiste hacer en row_number() OVER (ORDER BY cc.fecha) AS contador
pero sería algo simular puede para tu caso no sea row_number en particular la que necesitas; así que será ver otras [funciones para elegir la que corresponda](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html)) que represente el registro anterior

Al "final", sería hacer algo como lo siguiente (asumiendo/considerando para el ejemplo) con tu nueva columna `contador`:

```
WITH resumen AS
(
SELECT

      row_number() OVER (ORDER BY cc.fecha) AS contador,
      dc.id,
      dc.id_comp,
      dc.concepto,
      tc.nombre AS tipo_comprobante,
      cc.fecha,
      cc.id AS id_cc,
      dc.debe,
      dc.haber,
      (dc.debe - dc.haber) AS Saldo /* Calculamos el saldo */

      FROM detalle_comprobantes dc

      INNER JOIN comprobantes_contables cc ON cc.folio_comp = dc.id_comp
      INNER JOIN tipo_comprobantes tc ON tc.id = cc.tipo_comp

      WHERE dc.empresa = 2 AND cc.empresa = 2 AND dc.cuenta = 2104003 AND cc.fecha BETWEEN '2021-09-01' AND '2021-10-30' ORDER BY cc.fecha, tc.id, cc.folio_comp ASC
)
SELECT 
   R1.*,
   (R1.Saldo - IFNULL(R2.Saldo, 0))AS NuevoSaldo /* Usamos el saldo */
FROM resumen R1
LEFT JOIN resumen R2 on (R2.contador+1)=R1.contador
```

Nota:

> El saldo que se calcula *aquí* no es con lo de fechas/registros anteriores; solo con el inmediato anterior al que se procesa. Esto para que lo tomes en cuenta.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Estimado, muchas gracias por responder. Efectivamente, la idea de usar row_number() es generar un correlativo para no tener que hacerlo desde código. Ahora bien, revisé tu código y efectivamente realiza un cálculo, pero incorrecto. Traté de modificarlo pero sin resultados positivos. Según la tabla en mi publicación, el nuevo saldo debería ser: 1.- 1.672.432, 2.- 2.428.976, 3.- 3.281.183, 4.- 3.688.300, 5.- 5.202.120, 6.- 6.446.642 recordando que el nuevo saldo se genera del saldo anterior + debe - haber excepto en la primera fila o registro. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.